# get all the responses from the flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to get all the responses from flux but sometimes I'm getting all the response and sometimes I'm not getting only few responses. Can anyone please help me on this. I have attached the picture for reference. I don't want to subscribe to that flux. I want those data's for manipulation.

urls i have key as name and url as value.

```
    public LinkedHashMap<String String> getDummyHealthData (Map<String Strings urls) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> urlMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
Mono.when(Flux. fromStreamCurls.entryset().stream().log().flatmap(url->webclientBuilder.build().get().uri(url.getValue()).retrieve().bodyToMono (string.class). onSuccessorError((res,err)->{ urlMap.put(uri.getKey(),res);    )}
        ).OnErrorResume (e->Mono.empty)).block(); System.out.println(urlMap) 
 return urlMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onErrorResume` operator will not help you to resume the stream.
If you want to get all response, you need to process error.
You can write `doOnError` to process exceptions. Code may be below:
`doOnError(e -> urlMap.put(uri.getKey(), "defaultString"))`